# Blender to unity wrong armature position (feet)

Tags: animation, export, unity

The problem is that Unity misreads bone positions. Look at the feet -> it goes down. Everything is fine in the blender and the feet are on the ground as they should. Anyone know what this could be a problem with? I will add that before that everything worked well. It broke after exporting new shoes to the unit: /

[image: export options]
[image: unity view]
[image: blender view]

Comment: Are you using humanoid avatar?

Comment: Yes, base model with armature is body then shoes is exported with armature also. but just body is on humanoid rig, (humanoid in unity) and earler it worked fine but now i  have sad foot fingers.